# django - primary key in search_fields?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have thousands of objects for a django model in my database and I want to be able to search by primary key.

I know I can just go to `/admin/my_app/my_model/pk/` to enter into the admin for that particular object, but I want to be able to see it in the search results, to see all the display fields.

When I add `'pk'` or `'id'` to the `search_fields`, I get this error:

`Cannot resolve keyword 'pk' into field. Choices are: ...`

So I'm guessing it's not possible straight away but wonder if there is a workaround?

Comment: Can you post your `models.py`?

Comment: There is nothing special about my model, I didnt define the primary key just using django's default pk.

Comment: Have you tried using 'id'? i did.

Comment: Yes, I tried id and it doesn't work